# Отправка post запроса с php скрипта находящегося на сервере

Tags: php, http, post

Пытаюсь отправить пост запрос с одного сервера на другой из php скрипта с помощью file_get_contents но на другой сервер ни чего не приходит. Возможно это не лучшее решение но с помощью curl тоже не получилось. 
 Вот код:

```
$data = http_build_query( 
     array(
          'user_id' => $userId, 
          'pos_id' => $posId, 
          'pos_speed' => $posSpeed
    )
);

$options = array('http' => 
array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n',
    'content' => $data
)
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents('http://62.***.***.***/', false, $context);
```

Comment: \r\n уберите..... заголовки = строка либо массив, если массив, пхп сам проставит переносы, если это необходимо. дока http://php.net/manual/ru/context.http.php

Comment: Убрал, результат так же нулевой...

Comment: на 62.***.***.*** создайте скрипт post.php и внутрь напишите var_dump($_REQUEST); затем данный запрос file_get_contents() на этот скрипт, что выдает echo $result?

Comment: Немного не понял что нужно сделать. Но скажу что у меня на том сервере есть html форма которая так же отправляет пост запрос на тот же скрипт и все работает. Так же с моего приложения на андроиде на тот скрипт уходит пост запрос и все срабатывает. То есть тут скорее всего сам пост запрос не отправляется вообще.

Comment: данный код без \r\n работает, проверил лично.

Comment: echo result возвращает все те значения которые я передал

Comment: значит ПОСТ запро работает.

Comment: Все спасибо разобрался, дело было в \r\n и немного в моей неграмотности.

Answer (score 1):

Правильный ответ - убрать \r\n

```
$data = http_build_query( 
     array(
          'user_id' => $userId, 
          'pos_id' => $posId, 
          'pos_speed' => $posSpeed
    )
);

$options = array('http' => 
array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content' => $data
)
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents('http://62.***.***.***/', false, $context);
```

Чтобы прописать несколько заголовков, `header` следует сделать массивом так:

```
$options = array('http' => 
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => array(
            'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-length: ' . str_len($query)
        ),
        'content' => $data
    )
```